# c# Alter property of a existing com+ application

Tags: c#, com+

We have got running a com+ application on client PCs with a property "RemoteServerName" on the "Activation"-Tab.

Is it possible to change the RemoteServerName entry programaticly within a c# application ?

I found the same entry in the registry but only changing it in the Component Services Dialog takes effect.

Comment: Is it your application? If not, why would you change the setting under the hands of the user and whatever application uses that COM+ application?

Comment: No its not my application. The background is, we have got two servers, the user should be able to choice which server he want to use via the c# application I will write. The c# app should alter this value and Start the third party app which uses the com+ application to connect to the server.